# FTP file upload failure Java

Tags: java, upload, ftp-client

I use Apache's FTPClient and FTPServer libraries in my Java project. Server and client are on the same machine.

My FTPServer is supposed to be a local server,nothing related to the Internet. I can connect to the FTPServer from the client(I get 230 as reply code) but i cant seem to do anything. I cant store or retrieve any files.

I read almost every question related to this matter but people who asked other questions were be able to send simple files and had trouble with sending files like pdf etc. I just need to send or retrieve text files.

Any suggestions?

```
        FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
        String host = "mypc";
        String Name = "user";
        String Pass = "12345";

        client.connect(host);
        client.login(Name,Pass);
        System.out.println("Reply Code: " +client.getReplyCode());


    File file = new File("C:\\.....myfile..txt");

        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("C:\\.....myfile..txt");
        boolean isStored = client.storeFile("uploadedfile.txt", in);
        in.close();
        client.logout();
        System.out.println("isStored: " +isStored);
```

I didnt put the real path names. It returns false,no exceptions etc. This might be because of they're on the same machine?

Edit: Turned out i needed write permission to send a file to ftpserver. By default, it doesnt give users write permission. How can i give users write permission using Apache's ftpserver library?

Comment: why you can't? exceptions, nothing happens? What is your code?

Comment: Might be just you don't have permissions. Tell us more, we are curious :)

Comment: If you're getting nothing back from the client code, why not whack logging on the server and see what's being logged?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem Solved:
This is how to give a user write permission. I added this snippet to server side and it worked.

```
List<Authority> auths = new ArrayList<Authority>();

Authority auth = new WritePermission();

auths.add(auth);

user.setAuthorities(auths);
```

There's term `Authority` written in this symbol -> `< >` after `List` and `ArrayList` in the first line. Site doesn't see words in `<>` symbol.